# Disable internal light on insignia chest freezer

Tags: light, freezer

I have an insignia 7 cubic foot chest freezer. It has an internal LED light that I would like to disable, I'm just not sure how. Perhaps someone has a recommendation?
Here is the info: The light turns off when the door is closed. There is nothing on the lip of the freezer that gets pressed down when the door is closed.
There may be a door switch inside the freezer, I'm just not sure how to access that.

Would it be dangerous to just cut the wires leading up to the light?
Thank you.

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: Remove the bulb / led unit.

Comment: @SolarMike that's what I wanted to do, but I can't because it's LED.

Comment: I'll attach a picture.

Comment: Put it back together and tape it over with a piece of black duct tape.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I'd do that, but I need the light not to work at all

Comment: Either undo the white plug or if need to cut the wires, should cap and tape them.  Do not just cut and leave them.  Why do you not want the light to work?

Comment: @crip659 I can just undo the white plug? (Sabbath observant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the white part is a plug, disconnect and you're done. If not, yes you could cut the wires, but if you do that you really should cap with wire nuts.

Based on the size, that's almost definitely low voltage. I'd put a piece of electrical tape over the white connector (the wire side, not the lighting board) and leave the lighting board in place, but disconnected, in case you want the light on when cleaning for Passover.

The switch may be magnetic, in which case disabling it is not easy like the old days of taping the switch down
(I have one taped down, one I made a metal slide in blocker for a plunger switch, and the others I removed the bulbs. I don't have anything new enough for LED lighting.)

Comment: The white part does come out - very easy to diconnect. Do I need to worry about any electricity?

Comment: Based on the size, that's almost definitely low voltage.

Comment: and given that the metal contacts on the board are touchable by inquisitive fingers, yeah very likely low voltage.